# File filter modification needed

Tags: java, android, apache

```
FileFilter fileFilter = new FileFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File pathname)
            {
                return !pathname.getPath().endsWith("file.tmp");
            }
        };
```

The file filter in above code returns all the file path from directory except the one that ends with "file.tmp".The problem is I want to add one more filter that returns all the file path from directory except the one that ends with "file.temp" and also "file.tmp".

And I have tried the code below but it doesn't work.

```
FileFilter fileFilter = new FileFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File pathname)
            {
                return !( (pathname.getPath().endsWith("file.tmp"))&&(pathname.getPath().endsWith("file.temp")));
            }
        };
```

Comment: If you only want to exclude either `file.tmp` OR `file.temp`, then the `&&` in your 2nd code snippet should be replaced with `||`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made wrong check (accepts all files that don't end with file.tmp and file.temp **at the same time**), while you need:

```
FileFilter fileFilter = new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname)
    {
        return !pathname.getPath().endsWith("file.tmp") && !pathname.getPath().endsWith("file.temp");
    }
};
```

or with `||`:

```
FileFilter fileFilter = new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname)
    {
        return !(pathname.getPath().endsWith("file.tmp") || !pathname.getPath().endsWith("file.temp"));
    }
};
```